# How to logout with GET request in SpringBoot WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

How do i configure `securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http)`  so that my application logs out on `GET /logout`?

I have `SpringBoot 2` `Spring 5` and `WebFlux`

I tried:

```
  http
    .logout()
      .requiresLogout(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/logout"))
      .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler("/after-life"))
```

Problem is, a `LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter` sits earlier than the `LogoutWebFilter` in the emitted `SecurityWebFilterChain`. In that there is a hardcoded `.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/logout")` - which causes my application to always emit a html page on a GET request.

I found no way to suppress the automatic logout page generation :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned in the **documentation**,

> The default is that Spring Security will generate a log in page at "/login" and a log out page at "/logout". If this is customized:
>   The default log in & log out page are no longer provided
>   The application must render a log in page at the provided URL
>   The application must render an authentication error page at the provided URL + "?error"
>   Authentication will occur for POST to the provided URL

**Custom configuration** to have default login and without default logout.

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity){

        LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter loginpage= new LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter();
        loginpage.setFormLoginEnabled(true);
        return httpSecurity
                .addFilterAt(loginpage, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.LOGIN_PAGE_GENERATING)
                .authorizeExchange()
                    .pathMatchers("/home").authenticated()
                        .and().formLogin()                      
                            .loginPage("/login")                         
                        .and()
                        .logout()
                        .logoutUrl("/logout").requiresLogout(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/logout"))
                        .and()

                .build();

    }
```

Comment: I checked, this does remove the logout page entirely, but doesnt really answer _How do i configure securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) so that my application logs out on GET /logout?_

Comment: @inquisitive updated with requires logout matcher and it is working fine.

Comment: You can ommit `logoutUrl` becase you rewrite it with `requiresLogout`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem but I am using OAuth2Login and the application is behind a reverse proxy with stripping a prefix and with using a `ForwardedHeaderTransformer`. Everything works good but a logout page has hardcoded path `/logout` so there is no way how to add custom prefix. And my solution is change logout url to `/logout-oidc`

```java
http.logout(logout -> logout
            .requiresLogout(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/logout-oidc"));
```

It is bad that there isn't method `setLogoutPageGenerating(boolean enable)` which can disable `LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter`