# Spring cloud Gateway with keycloak logout not work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to build application in which I am using Keycloak configuration and spring security with spring cloud gateway everything is working fine but when I am trying to logout it is not working.

Spring security configuration is as below:

```
spring:
security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: http://localhost:8280/auth/realms/Default
            user-name-attribute: preferred_username
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: Default123
            client-secret: Wk79csSdfgdffomzVX2nTlb2boYT9NrW
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:9000/login/oauth2/code/keycloak
            scope: openid
```

ANd Security Config file is as below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
    protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
        return new HttpSessionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerLogoutSuccessHandler keycloakLogoutSuccessHandler(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repository) {
        OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler successHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(repository);
        successHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("http://localhost:9000/app/logout");
        return successHandler;
    }

    private ServerLogoutHandler logoutHandler() {
        return new DelegatingServerLogoutHandler(new WebSessionServerLogoutHandler(), new SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler());
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http, ServerLogoutSuccessHandler handler) {
        // Authenticate through configured OpenID Provider
        http.authorizeExchange()
                .pathMatchers("/app/logout").permitAll()
                .pathMatchers("/app/").authenticated().and().cors().and().oauth2Login();

        // Also logout at the OpenID Connect provider
        http.logout(logout -> logout.logoutHandler(logoutHandler()).logoutSuccessHandler(handler));

        // Require authentication for all requests
        http.authorizeExchange().anyExchange().authenticated();

        // Allow showing /home within a frame
        http.headers().frameOptions().mode(XFrameOptionsServerHttpHeadersWriter.Mode.SAMEORIGIN);

        // Disable CSRF in the gateway to prevent conflicts with proxied service CSRF
        http.csrf().disable();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

I am not sure why it is not login out what configuration we are missing. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

if I understood your question correctly, you would like to configure standard logout url.

I've occured this problem too and found this way of solution:

```
// you need to add it to your SecurityWebFilterChain ServerHttpSecurity http configuration

// this logoutSuccessHandler allows redirection after success logout to "/v1/logout/success"
// you also need to provide @Controller which will return some response on it

http.logout(logout -> logout
        .logoutSuccessHandler((exchange, authentication) -> {
          ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getExchange().getResponse();
          response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
          response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/v1/logout/success"));
          response.getCookies().remove("JSESSIONID");
          return exchange.getExchange().getSession()
              .flatMap(WebSession::invalidate);
        })

// this allows to proceed logout via GET request to "/v1/logout"
        .requiresLogout(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/logout")));
```

It is based on combination of articles:
[Spring Security WebFlux logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59253949/spring-security-webflux-logout)
[How to logout with GET request in SpringBoot WebFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325464/how-to-logout-with-get-request-in-springboot-webflux)

Actually I spent several hours and a lot of tries to achieve this to be worked))

But this provides logout only for your Spring Gateway application, not for Keycloak server.

If you need to logout from Keycloak server, you need to implement ServerLogoutHandler and override its' logout method and pass it to your ServerHttpSecurity http.logoutHandler()